# Save Eloquent model with relation make two entries, why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

This is my controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request, $course_id){
    $price['value'] = $request->price;
    $price['desc'] = $request->desc;
    If ($request->promo === "on") {
        $price['promo'] = 1;
    } else {
        $price['promo'] = 0;
    }

    $course = Course::find($course_id);
    Price::create($price)->courses()->save($course);
    return redirect('/course/'.$course_id.'/edit');
}
```

For example if my request var have:

```
$request->price = 100
$request->desc = 'blablabla'
$request->promo = 'on'
```

After I submit the form I got two new rows with the same data:

Table prices:

```
id | price | desc      | promo
1  | 100   | blablabla | on
2  | 100   | blablabla | on
```

Some info on models, I've:

```
public function courses () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'course_price');
}
```

in prices model and:

```
public function prices () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Price', 'course_price');
}
```

in courses model.

Whats wrong?

Comment: what happen when you just use `Price::create($price);`

Comment: Always two prices rows without relation with course

Comment: show what `dd($price)` gives

Answer (score 0):

Try [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

```
$price = Price::create($price);
$price->courses()->attach($course_id);
```

instead of:

```
$course = Course::find($course_id);
Price::create($price)->courses()->save($course);
```

Comment: Just tested and I got the same result

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like you make double post request on

```
Price::create($price)->courses()->save($course);
```

create and save.
please try your code with

```
Price::create($price)->courses();
```